# Create query using more than 1 Checked Item from checkedListBox

Tags: c#, mysql

I have the code working fine for 1 checked item in the checked list box, and users can only currently select 1 item, but I would like for the users to be able to select more than one check box and loop through, so each of the "from "+ SwitchClause +". creates a new query and inserts the date also.

There is an example of what I need to achive at the bottom.

As each of the nodes is a new database this is the simplest way I could find of doing it.

Thanks for any help.

```
public String GetQueriesForDay(DateTime Querydate)
{
    string SwitchName = "";
    foreach (DataRowView row in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
    {
        SwitchName = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", SwitchName, (SwitchName == String.Empty) ? "" : "", row["name"]);
    }
    string SwitchClause = "";
    foreach (DataRowView row in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
    {
        SwitchClause = String.Format("{0}{1}node{2}", SwitchClause, (SwitchClause == String.Empty) ? "" : "", row["nodeid"]);
    }

    string Query;

    Query = String.Format("select '" + SwitchName + " - " + SwitchClause + "' as Switch_Name ,clngp_digits as Extn, cldp_talk_time, cost " +
                          "from "+ SwitchClause +".cr" + Querydate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + " where record_type = 'D' or record_type = 'C' " +
                          "union all " +
                          "select '" + SwitchName + " - " + SwitchClause + "' as Switch_Name ,cldp_digits as Extn, cldp_talk_time, cost " +
                          "from " + SwitchClause + ".cr" + Querydate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + " where record_type = 'D' or record_type = 'B'"
                          );

    return Query;
}
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CalculateDays();
        string SwitchClause = "";
        foreach (DataRowView row in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            SwitchClause = String.Format("{0}{1}node{2}", SwitchClause, (SwitchClause == String.Empty) ? "" : "", row["nodeid"]);
        }

        string SwitchName = "";
        foreach (DataRowView row in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            SwitchName = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", SwitchName, (SwitchName == String.Empty) ? "" : "", row["name"]);
        }

        string queryStr = "";

        for (DateTime date = Startdate; date.Date <= Enddate.Date; date = date.AddDays(1))
        {
            queryStr = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", queryStr, (date != Startdate) ? (date.AddDays(1) != Enddate) ? " UNION ALL " : " UNION ALL " : "", GetQueriesForDay(date));
        }


        string dataSource = IPtxt.Text;
        string tigerDatabase = "datasource =  " + IPtxt.Text + ";port=3306;DATABASE= " + SwitchClause + ";Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx";


        MySqlConnection tigercon = new MySqlConnection(tigerDatabase);
        MySqlCommand callrec = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Switch_Name,Extn, COUNT(*) as Total_Calls, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(cldp_talk_time/1000)) as Talk_Time, SUM(cost/100000) as 'Total_Cost' from (" + queryStr + ") t group by Extn order by Extn ASC ;", tigercon);

        try
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter ttrkvw = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            ttrkvw.SelectCommand = callrec;
            System.Data.DataTable dbdataset = new System.Data.DataTable();
            ttrkvw.Fill(dbdataset);
            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

            bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
            ttrkvw.Update(dbdataset);

            MySqlDataAdapter dap = new MySqlDataAdapter(callrec);
            System.Data.DataTable tblItems = new System.Data.DataTable();
            dap.Fill(tblItems);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

so the example below is what I would like to achive. so that for each loop it creates the 2 queries for each day and for each of the selected checked items. THe node. is the value of the checked item. Also if it helps the word NodeX is the database name and the table are formatted as CRYYYYMMDD.

```
//Currently the next 3 lines is what i get with the current code and node1 selected in my checkbox.     
    select clngp_digits as Extn, cldp_talk_time, cost from node1.cr20140130 where record_type = 'D' or record_type = 'C'
    union all
    select cldp_digits as Extn, cldp_talk_time, cost from node1.cr20140130 where record_type = 'D' or record_type = 'B'
// If I have 2 checkbox selected then I would like the same as above with the other checkbox value I would then like it scaleable so if 10 check boxes are selected it will loop 10 times.
    select clngp_digits as Extn, cldp_talk_time, cost from node2.cr20140130 where record_type = 'D' or record_type = 'C'
    union all
    select cldp_digits as Extn, cldp_talk_time, cost from node2.cr20140130 where record_type = 'D' or record_type = 'B'
```

Comment: Your expectations are not clear to me. Can you show an example of what you expect to be the end result?

Comment: Thank you for looking, I have tried to explain a little better, I am currently learning to code and have managed to get so far but a little stuck now.

Comment: How many switches are there and will they change over time? If there is one per day, I think that is bad design.

Comment: There is no limit on switches so I can go back to the drawing board..

Comment: Why do you create a table per day? You can group all results in one table I guess. When data volume is a problem, look at partitioning the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
where record_type in ('D', 'I', ...)
```

This just makes your code a little smaller. I suggest to create a view, which groups the tables you have to one, so querying will be a lot easier.

```
create view demo
as
select clngp_digits as Extn, cldp_talk_time, cost, record_type from node1.cr20140130
union all
select cldp_digits as Extn, cldp_talk_time, cost, record_type from node1.cr20140130
union all
select clngp_digits as Extn, cldp_talk_time, cost, record_type from node2.cr20140130
union all
select cldp_digits as Extn, cldp_talk_time, cost, record_type from node2.cr20140130
```

just query it like this then

```
select *
from   demo
where  record_type in ('D', 'I', ...)
```